# Why can't the PHP SDK set a Facebook session?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

When the Facebook session expires with my App, I have to use the Javascript SDK to create a new session. This is hugely annoying as it appears to the user that they are logged out occasionally as I do most of the detection server side. And then, when they reload the page and the javascript has executed, the session is recreated.

I am aware that I can fix this quite simply by using javascript to show a message saying 'please reload the page' (much like StackOverflow), however, I do not want my users to have to do this. I accept that the PHP SDK cannot do it, but is there any sort of hack I can do to achieve it myself using PHP instead of Javascript?

Can anyone explain why the PHP cannot do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is running on your server, which has nothing to do with Facebook's servers. Remember that cookies are locked to the originating domain. The cookie will appear to have been set by YOUR server, and have an originating domain of "yoursite.com", not "facebook.com".

JS, on the other hand, runs on the client, and any requests made to Facebook's servers will also obey any cookies set by the Facebook servers.

Comment: Can PHP not use curl or file_get_contents to request a PHP page that sets a cookie? Or do cookies not get included in these headers?

Comment: You can do whatever cookie operations you want, but any cookies your app sends to the client will be locked to YOUR server's domain. Your server cannot set a facebook cookie that would actually get send to facebook servers, because the cookie will only get sent BACK to your server. If this was possible, it'd be trivial for you to steal/set cookies on a user's banking website (e.g.)

Comment: No I completely understand that, I didn't mean that. The facebook domain must set the cookie for facebook, this is common sense. What I mean is, can my server call a page on the facebook domain using one of the aforementioned functions, to resultantly set the facebook cookie from the facebook server? For instance file_get_contents(facebook.com/cookie.php)? Or would this not work because it is still coming from my server?

Comment: If you could get the JS code on the client side to send you the facebook session cookie (name/value) pair, then you COULD hijack the user's facebook session and perform actions on FB on their behalf. Don't know offhand if FB does session hijacking prevention by tying cookies to particular IPs/UAs/whatever.

Comment: That is what I was going to do but didn't want to have to resort to it. Thanks anyway.